# Create a new column containing time since last event in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
ID    date           event_1   event_2 
 1    2016-01-03     False     False
      2016-02-07     True      False
      2016-02-18     False     True
 2    2016-01-01     False     True
      2016-01-04     False     False
      2016-02-02     True      False
      2016-02-04     False     False
      2016-02-05     False     True
```

`ID` and `date` are a `MultiIndex`.

The question is, I want to create two new  columns `time_1` and `time_2`. Those columns should show the time elapsed since the corresponding event, e.g.

```
ID    date           event_1     event_2   time_1    time_2
 1    2016-01-03     False       False     -          -
      2016-02-07     True        False     0          -
      2016-02-18     False       True      11         0
 2    2016-01-01     False       True      -          0
      2016-01-04     False       False     -          3
      2016-02-02     True        False     0          32
      2016-02-04     False       False     2          34
      2016-02-05     False       True      3          0
```

How can I create a function that calculates this in `pandas`, given that the date is an index?

The calculations are per `ID` and the events are unrelated.

Comment: Does event1 have anything to do with event2? Should the calculations be done per ID?

Comment: Why are there null values (`-`) ? Whats the logic for them?

Comment: @Joost The events are independent and the calculations is per `ID`. I am gonna edit the question. Thank you for your questions

Comment: @RafaelC The meaning of `-` are `None` or the equivalent in `pandas` for `Not a date time`

Comment: I know. I asked why are there null values? For example, why isn't the first value for `time_1` zero, and the second the difference between `2016-02-07` and `2016-01-03` ? What's the logic?

Comment: @RafaelC Sorry about the confusion. The first value of `time_1` is `None` because you don' t have any prior information. So you really don't know the time elapsed. The second value is `0` because the event happen in that date. Then the third value is `11` because there are 11 days between those two dates.

Comment: I just added a new row, hope that this clarifies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you reset the index so that ID and date are columns (just to make referring to them easier -- `df.index.get_level_values("date")` is kind of unwieldy) and you ensure that df["date"] is a real datetime column and not strings, I think it's pretty straightforward:

```
df["time_1"] = df["date"] - df["date"].where(df["event_1"]).groupby(df["ID"]).ffill()
df["time_2"] = df["date"] - df["date"].where(df["event_2"]).groupby(df["ID"]).ffill()
```

gives me

```
In [173]: df
Out[173]: 
   ID       date  event_1  event_2  time_1  time_2
0   1 2016-01-03    False    False     NaT     NaT
1   1 2016-02-07     True    False  0 days     NaT
2   1 2016-02-18    False     True 11 days  0 days
3   2 2016-01-01    False     True     NaT  0 days
4   2 2016-01-04    False    False     NaT  3 days
5   2 2016-02-02     True    False  0 days 32 days
6   2 2016-02-04    False    False  2 days 34 days
7   2 2016-02-05    False     True  3 days  0 days
```

which works because (using event_2 because it's more interesting as it has two different Trues) first we select only the "start" times:

```
In [176]: df["date"].where(df["event_2"])
Out[176]: 
0          NaT
1          NaT
2   2016-02-18
3   2016-01-01
4          NaT
5          NaT
6          NaT
7   2016-02-05
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and then we group by the IDs and forward fill the reference dates:

```
In [177]: df["date"].where(df["event_2"]).groupby(df["ID"]).ffill()
Out[177]: 
0          NaT
1          NaT
2   2016-02-18
3   2016-01-01
4   2016-01-01
5   2016-01-01
6   2016-01-01
7   2016-02-05
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

after which we simply need to subtract to get the timedeltas.  You can use

```
df["time_1"] = df["time_1"].dt.days
df["time_2"] = df["time_2"].dt.days
```

to get to floats instead of timedeltas if you prefer.

Comment: Could you add the code for unsetting the indices and then recovering them up?